# Rx: получение коллекции событий из "окна" - не выходит красиво избежать deadlock'а

Tags: c#, linq, reactive

у меня есть источник собитий `source` и он выдает по несколько событий за короткий промежуток времени, а потом молчит. я чуть не написал свою реализацию `Window`, нашел [реализацию](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html) в доках, но наткнулся на deadlock.

---

вот как пытаюсь преобразовать `IObservable<T>` в `IObservable<IList<T>` (все события, которые получил в течении этого `окна` закинуть в список):

```
source.Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(obs => obs.ToListObservable())
```

по задумке, оно должно было блокировать вывод резултирующего события до окончания `окна`, но вместо этого просто делает deadlock.

---

подскажите как это реализовать без ручной обработки колбеков внутреннего `IObservable`

---

**UPD:**
хочу слоить 2 события в одно окно. чтобы первое событие начинало отсчет окна, а потом окно само закрывалось через TimeSpan. тестирую кодом:

```
var source = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));

var output = source.Window(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(700)).SelectMany(window => window.ToList());

using var subscription = output
    .Subscribe(list => Console.WriteLine(">>" + string.Join("; ", list)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**UPD2:**
все еще пытаюсь настроить "Окно", чтобы работало как "выключатель": включаешь - начинает запись, выключаешь - заканчивает запись и появляется возможность включить.

```
var state = false;
var output = source.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))
    .Window(source.Where(next => state == false).Select(next=>
    {
        state = true;
        return DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(610);
    }), time => source.Where(next =>
    {
        var shellEnd = time < DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (shellEnd)
        {
            state = false;
        }
        return shellEnd;
    }))
    .SelectMany(window => window.ToList());
```

тут все еще есть проблемы:

- иногда приходит ТРИ события в список вместо ДВУХ
- задержка `Delay` часто не помогает. она должна немного откладывать вызов событий, чтобы окно открывалось/закрывалось прямо перед распространением события

Comment: А что именно вы хотите получить? Опишите.

Comment: Может, вот это пригодится: https://pastebin.com/X7Xqibpj

Comment: судя по тексту, вам нужен [Throttle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229400(v=vs.103))

Comment: @VladD описал в UPD

Comment: @tym32167 еще не смог заставить работать `Window` как надо - присматриваюсь к `Throttle` и похожим инструментам

Comment: @dgzargo: Мой код делает следующее: первое событие открывает окно, а если в течение `TimeSpan` была тишина, то окно закрывается. Подходит?

Comment: А чем код из UPD не подходит? У меня он работает.

Comment: @VladD, нет, это как обычный `Buffer`. я ищу способ чтобы тот TimeSpan начинался только после того как первым событием оно активировало закрытие окна

Comment: в UPD оно делает окна без всего этого. результат ожидал вот такой: в каждое окно попадает всегда ДВА события.

Comment: @dgzargo: `var output = source.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(700));`? Сейчас перепроверю, делает ли он то, что надо.

Comment: `Buffer` еще менее гибкий, он не подходит

Comment: @VladD, так долго ищу решение, что код из `js` начинает протекать в `C#` )

Comment: @dgzargo: Кажется, вот это делает то, что нужно: `var output = source.Window(() => source.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500))).SelectMany(window => window.ToList());`.

Comment: Вроде всё правильно и должно работать.

Comment: @dgzargo: Но! Если ваш `source` холодный, нужно его превратить в горячий при помощи `.Publish().RefCount()`. Код основывается на том, что потоки в `Window` и в `Delay` совпадают.

Comment: @VladD гениально! - кидай в "ответы"!

Comment: @dgzargo: Отлично, сейчас сделаю :)

Comment: @dgzargo: Держи канонический ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `Window` очень мощная, позволяет разбить последовательность на мелкие кусочки («окна»), и контролировать вручную границы этих окон. Нам пригодится перегрузка с `Func<IObservable<TWindowClosing>> windowClosingSelector` (описание смотрите, например, [тут](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html), прокрутите до «RxNET Window» и распахните спойлер).

Эта перегрузка `Window` работает так. Первое окно открывается немедленно, и вызывается генератор закрывающего события: генератор возвращает `IObservable<T>`, и по приходу первого элемента окно закрывается. Тут же открывается новое окно, и вновь запрашивается генератор сгенерировать новое закрывающее событие. И так далее.

В качестве генератора закрывающих событий нам удобно использовать оператор `Delay`, применённый к исходной последовательности: он свдигает все элементы, *начиная от текущего*, на фиксированный временной промежуток. В результате при вызове генератора первым сгенерированным элементом будет следующий *ещё не выданный на текущий момент* времени элемент исходной последовательности, сдвинутый по времени на желаемую ширину окна. То есть окно закроется через заданный промежуток времени после прихода первого элемента.

Получив нужные окна, легко схлопнуть их в список про помощи простого `.ToList()`.

Результирующий код:

```cs
var windowDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);
var output = source.Window(() => source.Delay(windowDuration))
                   .SelectMany(window => window.ToList());
```

Обратите внимание, что мы не можем закешировать `source.Delay(windowDuration)`, т. к. нам нужно состояние именно на момент вызова.

---

Если ваш `source` холодный, и производит разные последовательности для разных подписчиков, нужно его превратить в горячий при помощи `.Publish().RefCount()`. Код основывается на том, что потоки в `Window` и в `Delay` совпадают.

Comment: кешировать можно, но `IObsevable` в `Window` закидовать **только через делегат**

Comment: я уже `state machine` пытался сделать, чтобы работало как _выключатель_ для _окон_. не нашел такого в библиотеке - свой начал делать (вышел убогим, но рабочим). с ним я поздно открывал и поздно закрывал окна - не самые приятные баги. а оно так просто и красиво решилось...

Comment: @dgzargoL ага, я тоже сначала подумал про state machine, но вручную делать всё же не лучшая идея

Comment: нет, вообще плохая идея, но лучше чем ничего. кстати, `state machine` через `Aggregate` делается - я только что это понял.

Comment: @dgzargo: Хм, скорее [`Scan`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.9/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Scan__1.htm)? но его нету в стоковом LINQ...

Comment: @dgzargo: Зато он есть у Rx: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh212007(v=vs.103)